# If every pair of non empty open sets have non empty intersection, then it is hyperconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that, in a topological space if every pair of non empty open sets have non empty intersection, then it is hyperconnected.

Steen and Seebach has already proved this theorem. But I failed to search and find their paper online. The converse part of this theorem is known to me.

> A topological space $X$ is said to be hyperconnected if closure of each open set is $X$.

Comment: For some reasons, all definitions of *hyperconnected* that I could google, refer to people having smartphones :)  --  But then this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space reveals the property you give as **definition**. So what is your question?

Comment: A topological space X is said to be hyperconnected if closure of each open set is X. Take this as definition.

Comment: Tommy Seebach? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3YXjY7sGEo

Answer (score 4):

The following are equivalent for any space $X$:

1. Any two open non-empty subsets of $X$ have non-empty intersection.
2. $X$ cannot be written as the union of two proper (i.e $\neq X$) closed subsets.
3. Every non-empty open set of $X$ is dense (i.e $\overline{U} = X$).
4. Every proper closed set has empty interior.

Proof:

1. implies 2. : Assume 1. Suppose $X = C\cup D$,where $C,D$ are closed.
   Then $(X\setminus C) \cap (X\setminus D) = X\setminus (C \cup D) = \emptyset$ by de Morgan, so 1. implies that $X\setminus C$ or $X\setminus D$ is empty (they are open, so cannot both be non-empty). So $C=X$ or $D=X$.
2. implies 3.: Suppose $O$ is non-empty open. If $C = \overline{O} \neq X$, then $X = C \cup (X \setminus O)$ writes $X$ as a union of two proper closed sets, which cannot be.
3. implies 4.: If $C$ is closed, $C \neq X$, and suppose that $O:= \operatorname{int}(C) \neq \emptyset$. Then by 3. $X =\overline{O} \subseteq \overline C = C \neq X$, contradiction. So 4. holds.
4. implies 1.: Suppose $U$ and $V$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$. If $U \cap V = \emptyset$, $U \subseteq X\setminus V$, so $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq \operatorname{int}(X \setminus V)$, contradiction with 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex and Henno.

Comment: @BirojitDas perhaps you should accept this answer

Answer (score 3):

Let $U \subset X$ be open and non-empty. If $\overline U \neq X$, then $X - \overline U$ is a non-empty open set that doesn't intersect $U$; this contradicts your hypothesis.